# How to Dynamically Fit image in screen using css

Tags: html, css, image

Hi guys this most be duplicate question, but i spent a day to search for the answer, and didn't find what i'm looking for.

the question is simple:

I have a simple HTML page, i want to set a background for it, to cover the whole screen at any time. and then, i want to put an image on the screen, to always be at center, and resize when i change the window size.

like this:

[image]

my problem is that i cant fix the images by height, because my background image is wide,and can cover any screen, and "My Image" is tall, and i want it to always be shown in the screen.

(note that the gray part is the overflow of the background image, because its wide and covered the whole screen )

tnx for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so here is your website's code revisited :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>گالری کاکتوس</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            background-image: url(http://cactuspics.com/content/wp-content/themes/mobile/images/4.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
        }
        #image {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url(http://cactuspics.com/content/wp-content/themes/mobile/images/body.png);
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-color: transparent;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="image"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

nice and clean :)

Answer (score 0):

Some jQuery magic might be needed here. Something like (untested) :

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var h = $(window).height();
    $('#image').height(h);
});
```

To be executed after DOM is loaded of course.

Comment: tnx for your fast answer. but isn't there a way to do this only with CSS and HTML?

Comment: I can't think of any way right now, but if you post an example I could have a look at it.

Comment: It probably won't be compatible with every browsers though

Comment: sure sir. here is the exact page i want to make. http://cactuspics.com/mindex.php